# count values in jquery ajax in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to display the total no of count values in casual and personal leave. For example if i choose casual leave, total no of causual leave count as 6 and personal leave count as 12 (mention in leavetype table attached in screenshots) and how many of days they have to use(mention in leave_application table attached in screenshots)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHu6P.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bz0DK.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTxr0.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCpnV.jpg)

This is my jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
      $('#select').change(function()
      { 
        showval=$(this).val(); 

        $.ajax({  
          type:'GET',
          url: '<?php echo $base_url;?>user/ajaxleave',         
          data : { 'employee_id': showval}, 
          success:function(data)
          {   
           countleave = $('.productprice-'+showval).val(data); 
          },
        }); 
        $('#hiddenval').val(showval);
        $('.show_selected').html("Your Total leave:  and your remaining leave :");           
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

This is my view code :

```
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div>
                <label class="form-control-label">Leave Type</label>
                  <select name="leavetype" class="form-control" id="select">
                      <option value="select">Select</option>  
                        <?php foreach($leavetype as $leaveappln_info){ ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $leaveappln_info->leavetype_id?>"><?php echo $leaveappln_info->leavetype_name; ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>  
                  </select>
              </div>
          </div>   
          <div class="show_selected"></div>
          <input type="hidden"  value="" id="hiddenval"> 
          <input type="hidden" value="" class="productprice" id="productprice">

          <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div>
                  <label class="form-control-label">Start Date</label>
                  <input type="date" name="start_date" class="form-control startdate" placeholder="Start Date" id="startdate" required onchange="cal()">
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div>
                  <label class="form-control-label">End Date</label>
                  <input type="date" name="end_date" class="form-control enddate" placeholder="End Date" id="enddate" required onchange="cal()">
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div>
                  <label class="form-control-label">Count Days</label>
                  <input type="text" name="count_days" class="form-control" placeholder="Count Days" id="countdays" readonly>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div>
                  <label class="form-control-label">Reason</label>
                  <textarea name="reason" class="form-control" placeholder="Reason"> </textarea> 
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

This is my Controller :

```
public function ajaxleave()
{
    $employee_id = $this->input->get('employee_id');     
    $this->db->where('leaveappln_id',$employee_id); 
    $result=$this->db->get('leave_application')->row();  

    $this->db->where('leavetype_id',$result->leavetype);
    $leavetype=$this->db->get('leavetype')->row();  
    echo $leavetype->leavetype_name;            
}
```

Comment: Please show you expected a result

Comment: If i choose personal leave it will be like : Your Total leave:12 days and your remaining leave : 12 days...........when the remaining leave will decrease depends upon the leave taken

Comment: Kindly help me anyone ..

Comment: do you mean you want to set the countleave to be the value of Total leave?

Comment: yes..... @Franz

Answer (score -1):

If you want to set the countleave to be the value of total leave edit your script like this

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
      $('#select').change(function(){ 
        showval=$(this).val(); 

        $.ajax({  
          type:'GET',
          url: '<?php echo $base_url;?>user/ajaxleave',         
          data : { 'employee_id': showval}, 
          success:function(data)
          {   
            $('.show_selected').html(`Your Total leave: ${data}  and your remaining leave : ${data} `);
          }
        });            
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

**Please take note that i use backticks (`) not single qoutes (')**

Hope this helps you!

**Edit:**

edit your controller

```
public function ajaxleave()
{
    $employee_id = $this->input->get('employee_id');     
    $this->db->where('leaveappln_id',$employee_id); 
    $result=$this->db->get('leave_application')->row();  

    $this->db->where('leavetype_id',$result->leavetype);
    $leavetype=$this->db->get('leavetype')->row();  
    echo $leavetype->leave_count;            
}
```

Take note i updated the script too.

Comment: The output will return as:--------  "Your Total leave: [object Object] and your remaining leave : [object Object]" ------like this...@Franz

Comment: what is your ajaxleave function returning in your controller?

Comment: please var_dump $leavetype from your controller then tell me what's the value

Comment: when i click casual leave it will return as----------object(stdClass)#22 (7) { ["leavetype_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["employeetype"]=> string(1) "3" ["leavetype_name"]=> string(14) "Personal Leave" ["leave_count"]=> string(2) "12" ["duration"]=> string(1) "1" ["leavetype_status"]=> string(1) "1" ["joinon"]=> string(10) "2019-08-27" } Personal Leave

Comment: when i click personal leave it returns --------------object(stdClass)#22 (7) { ["leavetype_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["employeetype"]=> string(1) "3" ["leavetype_name"]=> string(12) "Casual Leave" ["leave_count"]=> string(1) "6" ["duration"]=> string(1) "2" ["leavetype_status"]=> string(1) "1" ["joinon"]=> string(10) "2019-08-27" } Casual Leave

Comment: you want to get only the leave_count?

Comment: if you want to get only the leave_count ill edit my answer

Comment: I want to display leavetype count like personal leave total count and personal leave remaining count(based on leave taken) for a paricular employee

Comment: please accept my answer if it solved your problem , Thank you :)

Comment: Its working but thats return wrong values...wait I will explain clearly the logic..employee has only 12 personal leave and 6 casual leaves in a year.If they have taken 2 personal leaves already and after requesting for leave(personal leave) that time choosing a personal leave it will display you have total 12 personal leave your remaining personal leave : 10(already taken 2 leaves)